# Problem adding the Square.Connect nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget, square-connect

I have been trying to add the Square.Connect nuget package so that I can integrate with the square up payment system.

When I am trying to add the package I am getting an error:

"Could not install package 'Square.Connect 2.14.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

I have tried on a new application using .net 3.5 and .net 2.0 but I get the same error but with the changed target version.

Has anyone been able to get around this or can you advise me what I maybe doing wrong?

Comment: Added tag. Clarified.

Answer (score 0):

According to nuget.org https://www.nuget.org/packages/Square.Connect/ the Square.Connect package is for .NETStandard 2.0. So you should target that. Hint: Expand dependencies on the nuget page, to see what it requires.

Comment: Is possible with real-time inventory sync with square and Magento 1.x?  @Palle Due

Answer (score 0):

This package is incompatible with your project.

You should target .NET Standard 2.0  **or** .NET Full Framework 4.6.1 or higher.

Both can work with .NET Standard 2.0 assemblies.

.NET Core 2.0 too, but that's not usefull for you, I guess!

Answer (score 0):

As Palle Due's answer says, the [package information page for the most recent version of the package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Square.Connect/) lists .NET Standard 2.0 as a dependency. Therefore, your project must target something compatible with .NET Standard 2.0. [This table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) lists several compatible runtimes, such as .NET Framework 2.6.1 or higher, .NET Core 2.0 or higher, as Schwarzie2478's answer listed (but he didn't give source information, which I think is useful). The table also lists minimum versions for some other runtimes like Xamarin's Android/iOS, or Unity game engine.

However, if you look at some older versions of the package, [2.10.1.297](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Square.Connect/2.10.1.297) and earlier depend on .NET Framework 4.5. Therefore, if for some reason you can't target a newer version of the .NET Framework, you could use these older versions of the package. Although I don't know any reason why anyone would be stuck on such an old version of the Framework. .NET Framework lifecycle is complex and very difficult to find a table with actual dates, but my guess is that no supported server operating system is limited to .NET Framework 4.5, so any server installing security updates will probably be on .NET Framework 4.6.x or more likely 4.7.x, so I really don't see any good reason to stay on net45.